# Left and right derivatives of characteristic function $X_Q$

Tags: measure-theory, derivatives

Find the left and right derivatives of a characteristic function of $Q$.

**My attempt:** I tried deriving the result from the definition of right and left derivatives, which are $$D^+f(x)=\lim\limits_{h \to 0}\left[\sup\limits_{0<|t|\leq h}\frac{f(x+t)-f(x)}{t}\right] \text{  and  } D^-f(x)=\lim\limits_{h \to 0}\left[\inf\limits_{0<|t|\leq h}\frac{f(x+t)-f(x)}{t}\right]$$

Now, let $Q$ be a set of rationals where $f(x) = 1$ for every $x\in Q$, and $f(x) = 0$ otherwise. Now, we see that for $x\in Q$, no matter how small $h$ is, we can always find $t<0$ such that $f(x+t) = 0$. Therefore, $f(x+t) - f(x) = -1$, so for $t<0$, $D^+f(x) =  \infty$.  Similarly, for $x\in Q$, $D^-f(x) = -\infty$ as there exists some $t>0$ such that no matter how small $h$ is, $f(x+t) = 0$.

Similarly, for $x\notin Q$, no matter how small $h$ is, there exists a $t\in (0,h)$ such that $x+t\in Q$. Thus, $D^+f(x) =  \infty$ in this case. Obviously, since we can always pick $t$ such that no matter how small $h$ is, $x+t\notin Q$. Thus, $D^-f(x) = 0$.

Can anyone please help review my argument above to see if it's correct? If not, please help correct it if you can.

Comment: Nobody minds helping verify my solution above? I'm skeptical about the case when $x\notin Q$, whether there is such a $t\in (0,h)$ such that $x+t\in Q$ for any $h$. But I think this is true, since $Q$ is always dense in $R$ (aka, between any $2$ irrational numbers $x+h$ and $x-h$, there must be a rational number). Is this correct?

Comment: You are correct.  Between any two real numbers $x$ and $y$ there is a rational number.  It does not matter if one or both of $x$ and $y$ is irrational.

Comment: @RRL: Thanks for your help. So the left and right derivative above is correct? Since they are all $+/- \infty$ for all but one cases, I'm quite surprised:D

Comment: I don't think the last one is correct. If $x \notin \mathbb{Q}$ then $f(x) = 0$ but there exist a $t<0$ such that $\forall h \in \mathbb{R}$ $0<|t| \leq h$ and $(x+t) \in \mathbb{Q}$ thus $f(x+t) = 1$ and $D^{-}f(x) = -\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

My answer only disagree with you on $D^+(x), x \in Q$.

$x \in Q \Rightarrow f(x) = 1$

i) $x + t \in Q \Rightarrow f(x + t) = 1 \Rightarrow \frac{f(x+t)-f(x)}{t} = \frac{1-1}{t}=0$

ii) $x + t \in \sim Q \Rightarrow f(x + t) = 0 \Rightarrow \frac{f(x+t)-f(x)}{t} = \frac{0-1}{t}= \frac{-1}{t}$

Hence, $\sup \frac{f(x+t)-f(x)}{t} =0$ , for $0 < t \le h$, of any $h$.

Thus, $D^+ (x)$= lim sup = lim {$0,0,…0,…$} = $0$